# Connecting to TFS to add (and maintain) version control for a MS-Access application

Tags: ms-access, version-control, msscci

I have been tasked with taking an existing application (written in Microsoft Access, running under the 2003 runtime) and getting it into our TFS 2012 version control system.

I thought I'd be able to use the 2012 MSSCCI provider to do so, but when I try to add the TFS server, while it allows me to pick http or https, the server name, and the server port, it does not allow me to enter the remaining path.

As such, I've been unable to get it to find my TFS server at `http://server:8080/tfs`, as the closest I can get with that interface is `http://server:8080` which does not exist, coming back with an HTTP code 404: Not Found.

I am not committed to using MSSCCI if there is an alternative that would work, but I do have to use TFS (I cannot set up another version control system just for this).

Comment: Wow - could you triple-check that you uninstalled all the other MSSCII providers and installed Team Explorer 2012 and the 2012 MSSCCI extensions?  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6  That sounds like the connect dialog from 2005...!

Comment: Yes, just before I posted the question I did exactly that. In fact, at that time I realized that I had the TFS 2010 tools and 2010 MSSCCI installed (which was showing me the whole `http://server:8080` path that it wasn't finding). Once I uninstalled it all and installed the 2012 versions of both, I still got the 404 error, except this time it didn't show me the path it was trying to find. In fact, under Programs and Features I can see the MSSCCI Provider v11.0.50912.0, which matches where I downloaded it from: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b5b5053e-af34-4fa3-9098-aaa3f3f007cd